# Centos release 7.3.1611 Extend Swap partition from current 1GB to 2GB

Tags: centos, partition, swap

Could someone who has a deep knowledge can try explain how to achieve and increase a swap memory from 1 to 2G?

I'm running Centos on Oracle Virtualbox.

After utilized a command **lsblk** :

```
sda               12G   disk
|--sda1           1G    part /boot
|--sda2           1G    part
   |-centos-root  8,1G  lvm  /
   |-centos-swap  1G    lvm [SWAP]
sr0               1024M
```

**fdisk -l:**

```
/dev/sda1        Linux
/dev/sda2         Linux LVM
```

Looking forward for detailed explanation from community.

Aidas

Comment: This looks very like a homework or a test question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have enough free space in your volume group, you can verify how much you have with `vgs`. Because swap cannot be resized, you need to remove your existing swap first: stop it with `swapoff` and then remove the logical volume with `lvremove centos/swap` and create new bigger LV with `lvcreate -n swap -L2G centos` and format it as swap `mkswap /dev/mapper/centos-swap`.

If your swap is referred in `/etc/fstab` by UUID you either need to update it or save the old swap's UUID and when creating the new one use `-U <old UUID>` to create the swap with the same UUID.